# SNMP atomically get interfaces and counters

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have some switches and routers that should be monitored over SNMP. Number of interfaces in switches and routers and their "suffix" in OID can change at an arbitrary moment.

How can I atomically get both interface name to OID suffix mapping and interested counters on this interfaces?

Comment: Since this is a "simple" protocol, I don't think atomic operations were ever seriously considered. You will have to embrace the sudden changes and leave rooms in your monitoring code to accept conflicts and possibly data loss.

Answer (score 1):

An SNMP `GET-NEXT` request can query multiple columns of a table at once. If you want, for example, the `ifInDiscards` and `ifInErrors`, along with the `ifDescr`, simply query for all three at once. Here's how to do it in the shell using `snmpgetnext` (`snmpwalk` doesn't appear to support this):

```
snmpgetnext <parameters> <host-ip> IF-MIB::ifDescr IF-MIB::ifInDiscards IF-MIB::ifInErrors
```

Here's the output on my machine:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifInDiscards.1 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.1 = Counter32: 0
```

Then, you will have to update your query with the `.1` from the previous response in order to get the results for the next interface:

```
snmpgetnext <parameters> <host-ip> IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 IF-MIB::ifInDiscards.1 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.1
```

Comment: But what will happen if between GET-NEXT request order of interfaces on agent will change?

Comment: The philosophy of SNMP is that agents (devices) are simple, the management application is complicated, and has to handle all those issues. You will have to detect re-indexing, and recover. This recovery will only be invoked rarely, eg. plugging network cards in/out, software interfaces appearing / disappearing, etc.

Comment: @KamilZaripov if you are using SNMPv2c or SNMPv3, you can use a `GET-BULK` request, which can return the results for several rows at once. For example, if you use `snmpbulkget -Cr2` for the initial query, instead of `snmpgetnext`, it will respond with the values for (up to) the next two interfaces

Comment: Yes, at the end of the day I have stopped on GET-BULK with all interested OID prefixes and max-repetitions equal to the max number of interfaces that I expect on some agent.